# C# Elevate Current Running Process as SYSTEM

Tags: c#, process, system, elevated-privileges

How can I elevate current running process as system, not administrator.

```
try
        {
            var ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
            ps.FileName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.ToString() + ".exe";
            ps.Verb = "runas";
            this.Close();

            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = ps;
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception re)
        {
            this.TopMost = true;
            MessageBox.Show(re.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        finally
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

above code restarts current running program to administrator privilege, like wise how can I get SYSTEM privilege?

c# 4.5

Any chance to create a new process as SYSTEM ? cause I see some apps(RunAsSystem) can make a file start as SYSTEM process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PsExec from Microsoft SysInternals PsTools can start cmd as SYSTEM and from there you can do almost anything.
I am also searching for another way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way starting a process as system. This can be achieved only for boot time/kernel level scenarios, drivers, services etc.
It would be a security risk if that could be done. Create windows service if it is cruicial to you to run your logic as system.